# software for ssrs security and for subscription?

Tags: reporting-services

Could anyone suggest me software to manage security and subscriptions for SSRS reports. I have been searching google to find any software but no luck. any help would be much appreciate.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

That is what the Report Manager is for...

Go to `http://<servername>/reports` and you will be able to set up your report subscriptions and the security profiles for who can access what based on your Active Directory accounts.

Comment: sorry may be I should have ask this. I need a third party software. is there anything like that?

Comment: Why does it need to be third party?  What are you trying to do that the Report Manager cannot?

Comment: looking for the third party software for eg: to maintain subscriptions from user side. at the moment I am adding subscriptions from my side when ever user needs.  if there is a software which will allow user to add subscriptions of whatever particular reports they needs then that will save more time.

Comment: @Amelia  That **is** what the Report Manager is for.  I don't believe there is a third party solution as Microsoft's own Report Manager does it all and changes to the ReportServer database by anything other than SSRS is not supported.